# Global variables and html-page monitoring

Tags: javascript, html

How do I handle global variables?
I need one in my application as a global control variable. Where can I delete it? The counterpart to `window.onload()` would be great, but probably only exists in a similar way.

`window.onbeforeunload()` 
I tried this, it did not work